# Where clause on linq query against dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-objects, where-clause

**I have fixed the problem of it not listing the data which was related to a wrong field on the spawn dictionary but still i would like to question if the way I am approaching it is ok ?**

I have a few checkboxs that if true should add check the item status and include it on the list.

So not really knowing what to do, this is what I came up with:

```
        HashSet<int> status = new HashSet<int>();
        if (OptionsForm.filterPlayer.Checked) status.Add(0);
        if (OptionsForm.filterEnemy.Checked) status.Add(1);
        if (OptionsForm.filterSummon.Checked) status.Add(2);
        if (OptionsForm.filterNPC.Checked) status.Add(3);
        if (OptionsForm.filterObject.Checked) status.Add(4);
        if (OptionsForm.filterMonster.Checked) status.Add(5);
        if (OptionsForm.filterGatherable.Checked) status.Add(6);
        if (OptionsForm.filterUnk.Checked) status.Add(7);

        var query = from SpawnList item in spawnEntities.Values
                    where status.Contains(item.Status)
                    orderby item.Name ascending
                    select item;
```

But currently it is not returning me any errors or items that should have been returned.

spawnEntities is a dictionary with uint, SpawnList.

SpawnList is a simple class:

```
public class SpawnList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    // some more data not needed for the question
}
```

Comment: Is the status hashset filled correctly?

Comment: What happens when you enumerate the results?

Comment: Have you tried to enumerate query (or call `query.ToList()`)  ? Because LINQ query is executed only when you enumerates it...

Comment: it was my mistake, the status on the dictionary was wrong in 1 field and i was not getting what I wanted after listing all the data I noticed it heh, but is it ok to do it like I am doing ?

Comment: Yes, It sounds reasonable to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it was my mistake, the status on the
>   dictionary was wrong in 1 field and i
>   was not getting what I wanted after
>   listing all the data I noticed it heh,
>   but is it ok to do it like I am doing
>   ?

To avoid such mistakes, I would use enumerations instead of ints - just define

```
enum SomeStatus
{
    Player,
    Enemy,
    <.etc.>
}
```

and change

```
public int Status { get; set; }
```

into

```
public SomeStatus Status { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest the same thing. But you can also add that the status doesn't need to be a list, it can be a "combined enum" instead.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: Do you mean setting `[Flag]` attribute on `SomeStatus` and then combining the results of user input into one `SomeStatus` value via `|=` ? It strongly depends on the business meaning of `SomeStatus`, but generally I would not do that, as each single entity seems to have a concrete status - either `Player`, or `Enemy`, or something else - and making `SomeStatus` flagged enum would allow for statuses like `PlayerAndEnemy`, which may be incorrect. Again, depending on the requirements.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean (see my answer), and I see your point that it should be checked against the requirements.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable thanks, so basicly I would as well change my hash to use it right ?

Answer (score 0):

My comment to the previous answered byt further explained. You can use the `Flags` attribute instead, which will make it easier to check your status.

```
[Flags]
enum YourEnum
{
     none,
     Val1,
     Val2,
     Val3,
     Val4,
}
```

Set your status to:

```
public YourEnum Status {get; set;}
```

Create your combined status like:

```
YourStatus status = YourEnum.None;
if(OptionsForm.filterPlayer.Checked) status = status | YourEnum.Val1;
if(OptionsForm.filterEnemy.Checked) status = status | YourEnum.Val2;
<etc>
```

The you'll get a linq like:

```
    var query = from SpawnList item in spawnEntities.Values
                where status & itemStatus != YourEnum.None
                orderby item.Name ascending
                select item;
```

Read more about the flags attribute here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx